# Timestamp for start of week in mySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I have a timestamp field in a table as an integer like 1429198764 (04/16/2015 @ 3:39pm (UTC)) and I want to calcuate the timestamp of the start of the week for this timestamp (assuming the week starts on a Monday) which would be 1429142400 (04/16/2015 @ 12:00am (UTC))

For the timestamp of the start of the day I can use:
`unix_timestamp(from_unixtime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'))`

And for the start of the hour I can use:
`unix_timestamp(from_unixtime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00'))`

But stumped on how to get the start of the week.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek. given that, you can figure out what day monday should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `DATE` datatype, the expression to return the previous Monday is fairly simple (though maybe not that straightforward):

```
  dt - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(dt) DAY
```

The MySQL `WEEKDAY` function returns 0 if `dt` value is a Monday, a `1` if it's Tuesday, etc.

So, if `dt` is a Tuesday, we just need to subtract 1 day from it, and we're back at the previous Monday. The `WEEKDAY` function just happens to return an integer value that's very convenient for us to use. If we need to back up to `Sunday` instead, then we could use the MySQL `DAYOFWEEK` function instead.

The same pattern can be used with `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` datatypes. If we want to back up to midnight, we just need some additional expressions to handle truncating the time portion.

The conversion from an integer value to MySQL `TIMESTAMP` adds some clutter, but the pattern remains the same. Just substitute `dt` in the example above with your expression that returns the MySQL `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Thanks that worked great. He's the resulting SQL for anyone else in the same boat:

```UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(from_unixtime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(from_unixtime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')) day), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'))
```